# Does rsyslog configuration support case statement?

Tags: rsyslog

Does rsyslog support case statement similar to C?

```
switch ($programname)
​{
    case "nginx":
        // code to be executed if n is equal to constant2;
        break;
    case "java":
        // code to be executed if n is equal to constant2;
        break;
        ...
    default:
        // code to be executed if n doesn't match any constant
       break;
}
```

I know that same effect can be achieved by if..else if..else statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it doesn't, as you can easily learn yourself: 
https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/rainerscript/control_structures.html

Comment: I read the same documentation before asking the question. But I was skeptical that it might be buried somewhere else in documentation.